# How to change the default author in PhpStorm for PHPDoc

Tags: configuration, phpstorm, phpdoc

I search for a moment a way to change the name and mail used by PHPDoc in PhpStorm when you use the "autocomplete" by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing `/**` just before a class or a function.

Example :

```
/**
 * Class DepartmentType
 *
 * @author Foo Bar <foo.bar@email.com>
 */
class Foo
{
```

Because, this name and this mail is not the name and mail configure for the git I use in my project. I don't find any place to change this defaults values...

Anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Preferences > Editor > File and Code Templates > Includes tab > PHP Class Doc Comment

```
/**
 * Class ${NAME}
#if (${NAMESPACE}) * @package ${NAMESPACE}
#end
 * @author Foo Bar <foo.bar@email.com>
 */
```

I edited @Mahmoud Zalt's answer, which is basically right, but the edit was rejected, so here you go. @Mahmoud Zalt's answer will only work if you have a namespace in the class, which is what the if/end logic is looking for.

Comment: In PhpStorm 2016.2.2 I try to use the code snippet in "Settings". This is supposed to change it for the current project only.
Unfortunately clicking "Apply" will change it for all projects.
Any .idea?

Answer (score 10):

Create custom template variables and define their values right in the include template using the #set VTL directive.
For example, if you want to your full name inserted in the file header instead of your login name defined through the ${USER}, write the following construct:

#set( $MyName = "John Smith" )

.Ref: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html

My Solution:

Go to : Preferences > Editor > File and Code Templates > Includes tab > PHP Class Doc Comment

```
/**
 #set( $USER = "Javier Solis Flores ( @JavierTwiteando )" )
 * Created by ${PRODUCT_NAME}.
 * User: ${USER}
 * Date: ${DATE}
 * Time: ${TIME}
 */
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to: preferences > Editor > File and Code Templates > [Includes] > **PHP Class Doc Comment**.

example:

```
/**
 * Class ${NAME}
 * 
 * @category 
#if (${NAMESPACE}) * @package ${NAMESPACE}
#end
 * @author John Doe <John@mail.com>
 */
```

Comment: I've try to change the values after @author but that doesn't change anything, the old username and mail are always here when I create comments.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **PhpStorm 2017.1**:

File > Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates > [Includes] > PHP File Header

Here you can edit the comment.

Answer (score 1):

In PHPSTORM 2017.1 you can change it at

```
File -> Settings -> File and Code Templates -> Includes tab -> PHP File Header
```

Answer (score 1):

**PhpStorm 2021.2.1**

1:     Go to **File** -> **Settings**

[image: Go to File -> Settings]

2: Go to **File and code templates**
[image: Go to File and code templates]

3: Go to **includes** -> **PHP File Headers**
[image: Go to includes -> PHP File Headers]

For Syntax info [Phpstorm FileHeader](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-file-and-code-templates.html)

Answer (score 0):

Edit JVM options via JetBrain Toolbox. Append row:

```
-Duser.name=Foo Bar <foo dot bar at email dot com>
```

${USER} placeholder will be replaced with thist text everywhere.